# wpf binding resource to a template resource

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mahapps.metro

I'm using a custom resource to theme my controls, all controls are binded to this custom resource, I want to use code to bind this custom resource to default template property.
I'm trying
to change

```
        Application.Current.Resources("bgColor") = Brushes.White
```

to

```
        Application.Current.Resources("bgColor") = Application.Current.Resources("{TemplateBinding property="Backgorund"}")
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Backgorund is spelled Background, but that's not the problem ... if I understood you correctly you are setting it in the code behind, you can use "{TemplateBinding property="Backgorund"}" in XAML, but even there not in a way you posted it ...

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I tried all the methods on Google but I can't set it to whatever the template was. have some links where I can see examples?! thx. @MarkoDevcic

Comment: I presume you want to set the application resource in code ... Application.Current.Resources["YourObjectKey"] = new Uri( "/PathToYourDictionary", UriKind.Relative ); Note that the resources are accessed by indexer and you want to have your new resource in a Dictionary